# How to check the existences of all my tables? in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I want to check the existence of all my tables. Send 1 if all the tables do exist or 0 if one table or more is missing.

```
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='graphe';
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='proprieteindicateur';
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='graphe_proprieteindicateur';
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='utilisateurs';
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='profil';
select 1 from information_schema.tables tbl where tbl.table_name='droit';
```

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't replace the "1" with "count()" and use the "IN" statement with a list of table names?  If you can, create a function where the count is compared to your expected answer.  Then return 1 or 0 based on your result.

Comment: no reason, i just wanna be able to have one request that checks if the table exist and return 1 or 0. 

But can you give more details i didn't really understand what you meant .

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a single statement:

```
with table_list (name) as (
  values 
   ('graphe'),
   ('proprieteindicateur'),
   ('graphe_proprieteindicateur'),
   ('utilisateurs'),
   ('profil'),
   ('droit')
)
select count(*) = (select count(*) from table_list)
from information_schema.tables it
  join table_list l on it.table_name = l.name
and it.table_schema = 'public';
```

It will return `true` if all tables are found, and `false` if not.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that returns a 0 or 1 based on a condition.  For example (I do not have access to a Postgres database to check syntax!):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION checkTables()
RETURNS smallint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
cnt   smallint;
rntVal smallint;
begin
  SELECT count(1) 
  INTO cnt 
  FROM information_schema.tables tbl 
  where tbl.table_name IN ('graphe', 
                           'proprieteindicateur',
                           'graphe_proprieteindicateur', 
                           'utilisateurs', 
                           'profil',
                           'droit');

  if(cnt == 6)then
    rtnVal = 1
  else
    rtnVal = 0
  end if;
end;
return rtnVal;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you so muchhhh ! but i can't get it why it says :

 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ELSE"

Comment: may be missing a semi colon after "rtnVal = 1"?  You will have to play with it to make it work.  I do not have a syntax checker.

Comment: Haha okay thank you . I can't seem to succed right now but i'll find it.

Thanks a lot for your precious help!!

Comment: The comparison operator in SQL and PL/pgSQL is `=` not `==`. You can simplify this by changing the function to `returns boolean` and use `return cnt = 6`  at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that works quite good, but it's in shell.

```
PRESENCE_TABLE=$OK
for table in $LISTE_TABLE
do
    TABLE_EXISTE=$(psql -t -w -f $FILE_SQL_VERIF_MDD --set nom=\'$table\' | tr -d " ")
    if [ -z $TABLE_EXISTE ]
    then
        echo_log -e "La table $table n''existe pas en base."
        PRESENCE_TABLE=$KO
    fi
done


if [ $PRESENCE_TABLE -ne $OK ]
then
    echo_log -e "Il manque de(s) table(s) dans le modele de donnees, il faut relancer le script avec l'option ...."
    fct_exit $KO
fi
```

Hope it helps